# _api/web/siteusers does not return user until I check users permissions

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

if I query a user who hasn't signed in yet to our new SharePoint site using

```
_api/web/siteusers(@v)?@v='User i:0#.f|membership|someUser@amc.edu'
```

I get no results. If I then just go to permissions in SP online and check if `someUser` has permissions (which they may or may not have), then by merely checking `someUser`'s permissions now `_api/web/siteusers` behaves correctly.
i saw references to some links that handle the problem, but want to know how it works in sprLib.

Does anyone know how to ensure user in sprLib?

referred links:

- https://zimmergren.net/sharepoints-hidden-user-list-user-information-list/
- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233636/api-web-siteusers-does-not-return-user-until-i-check-users-permissions

Answer (score 0):

You could use rest api to ensure user.

```
function ensureUser(webUrl,loginName)
{
   var data = { 'logonName': loginName }; 
   return $.ajax({
      url: webUrl + "/_api/web/ensureuser",
      type: "POST",      
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
         "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
         "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
     "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
      }
   });  
}

var loginName = 'user login name'
ensureUser(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,loginName)
.done(function(data)
{
    console.log('success');
})
.fail(function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

Check user permission will call server side ensure user based on my experience so you could get by `_api/web/siteusers` after that.

Update:

Not sure you mean sprestlib.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/sprestlib@1.8.0/dist/sprestlib.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
    sprLib.rest({
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/ensureuser",
        data: "{ 'logonName': 'i:0#.f|membership|testa@xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com'}",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    })
        .then(function () { console.log("log"); })
        .catch(function (errMsg) { console.error(errMsg) });

</script>
```

Comment: thank you. i know for the possibility to use in rest api and Ajax request, but there is a way to do it with the sprLib Libary ? and if not, loginName need to be the the exec loginName in the siteusers?